# Ajax: request is going to the servlet but not returning back to the jsp page with updated values?

Tags: java, jsp

I am creating a simple application. I want to refresh the data of particular part on the basis of certain dropdown values but response from jsp page is going to servlet but not heading back to jsp page?

Code:

`<script type="text/javascript">`

`var xmlRequest;`

```
function changeCities() { 

xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

xmlRequest.open("get", "InitCustomerPageServlet?cityId=2", true); 

xmlRequest.send(null); 

xmlRequest.onReadyStateChange = processResponse; 

} 

function processResponse() { 

alert(1); 

if(xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200) { 

alert(xmlRequest.responseText); 

var response = xmlRequest.responseText; 

document.getElementById("res").value = response; 

} 

} 
</script>
```

`<body>`

```
<form action="post" name="customerRegForm"> 

    <select name="state" onchange="changeCities()"> 

      <option value="1">Gujarat</option> 

      <option value="2">Rajasthan</option> 

   </select> 
  <select name="cities">  </select> 

  <input type="text" name="res"></input> 

</form> 

   </body>
```

Comment: Can you provide an example. Did you rerender the part you wanted?

Comment: yes, i created a jsp page and send the request using ajax this goes into servlet and jsp page is still opened but with no data.

Comment: So as I said, can you post an example

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" >
var xmlRequest;

function changeCities()
{
 xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xmlRequest.open("get", "InitCustomerPageServlet?cityId=2", true);
 xmlRequest.send(null);
 xmlRequest.onReadyStateChange = processResponse;
}

function processResponse()
{
 alert(1);
 if(xmlRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlRequest.status == 200)
 { alert(xmlRequest.responseText);
  var response = xmlRequest.responseText;
  document.getElementById("res").value = response;
 }
 
}
</script>   script

Comment: <body>

<form action="post" name="customerRegForm">
<select name="state" onchange="changeCities()">
<option value="1">Gujarat</option>
<option value="2">Rajasthan</option>
</select>

<select name="cities">

</select>
<input type="text" name="res"></input>
</form>

</body>

Comment: It is suggested to write code in the question section with proper formatting rather than comments section. You can edit the question and do that.

Comment: Paste Servlet code also.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
document.getElementById("cities").innerHTML = response;
```

in script and

```
<select name="cities" id="cities">  </select>
```

in body tag.